# How to embed a teminal inside a pyside6 application on Windows enviroment

Tags: python, windows, powershell, terminal, pyside

I need to run a terminal inside a python application with pyside6, this application has to run in windows and Linux, I could already embed the application in linux without problems with this contribution [How to embed terminal inside PyQt5 application without QProcess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52269950/how-to-embed-terminal-inside-pyqt5-application-without-qprocess) and using urxvt terminal, on windows I can't find a solution that allows me to do the same, any solution that you suggest me? thanks in advance.

Already tried on Windows but with cmd.exe and also powershell.exe, with the path, with no success.

Comment: Why are you using python?  You can do everything in Powershell that you can do in python and a lot more.

Comment: We need to embed a terminal inside a python application for customer requirements, this application already has other features and this terminal inside is a necessary feature.

Comment: The call PS from inside a python script when you need system commands : https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/executing-powershell-from-python/

Comment: Read following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199594/xterm-on-windows